# Passing arguments to nodejs call backs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, https

I am creating a NodeJs application. I need to have the following functionality in it.

1. From the user data the location is requested using GoogleMap API.
2. From the JSON object received latitudes and longitudes are found out.
3. The longitude and latitudes are saved to the corresponding entries in MongoDB

I have got the following code

```
var options = {
    host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
    path: '/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=' + donor[j].pincode + '&key=AIzaSyD4M1TkzIl0nyKObyXtrCOgHJpN_BDPb6A'
}
https.request(options, callback).end();
callback = function (response) {
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        var loc = JSON.parse(str);
        console.log(loc.results[0].geometry.location.lat);
        Donor.collection.updateOne({email: email}, 
            { $set: { latitude: loc.results[0].geometry.location.lat, longitude: loc.results[0].geometry.location.lat } }, 
            false, 
            true);
    });
}
```

In this line:

```
Donor.collection.updateOne({email: email}, 
    { $set: { latitude: loc.results[0].geometry.location.lat, longitude: loc.results[0].geometry.location.lat } }, 
    false, 
    true);
```

I want to pass the email field from the calling function to check for that `email` and update the `latitide` and `longitude`.

How will I do that?

Comment: and where is that `email` you want to access?

Comment: Email is above the 'Donor.collection.updateOne line

Comment: I don't see any `email` except the one in the `updateOne` query